# Renomear todos os arquivos de uma pasta para nomes aleatórios

Tags: random, powershell

Preciso de um comando para renomear todos os arquivos de uma pasta para um nome aleatório, que mantenham a mesma extensão de arquivo e, de preferencia com números, o que eu consegui até agora foi isso:

```
forfiles /P c:\teste\ /c "cmd /c rename @path %RANDOM%.@ext"
```

porém o `%RANDOM%` coloca o mesmo número para todos os arquivos e como esses não podem ter o mesmo nome só acaba mudando um só.

Powershell é uma linguagem bem diferente do meu dia a dia por isso pergunto aqui uma solução de alguém com experiencia nele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$caminho = Get-Location # Pode alterar se quiser outro caminho que não o actual

# Lista todos os ficheiros que existam no caminho actual
foreach($ficheiro in $(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $caminho)) {

    # Guarda a extensão original do ficheiro 
    $extensao = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($ficheiro.FullName);

    # E cria um nome aleatório e altera a extensão para a extensão original do ficheiro
    $nomeAleatorio = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName(), $extensao)

    # Cria o nome caminho do ficheiro com base no caminho actual e no novo nome.
    $novoCaminho = Join-Path $(Split-Path $ficheiro.FullName -Parent) $nomeAleatorio

    Write-Host "A alterar o nome da ficheiro $($ficheiro.Name) para $nomeAleatorio"

    Move-Item -Path $ficheiro.FullName -Destination $novoCaminho
}
```

Se precisar de aplicar a mesma lógica a todos os ficheiros existentes no directório e nos sub directórios, adicione o *switch* `-Recursive` ao `Get-ChildItem`.